# Show menu tab on certain content type

Tags: views

I have created a menu tab with views and I want to show that tab only on a certain content type. How can I do this?

Comment: drupal 6? or 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this resource? http://drupal.org/node/354423 , if not, could be useful, is about a menu tab to show only with certain content type.